# What is "soft" about the soft actor-critic algorithm?

Tags: reinforcement-learning

I recently read the paper [Soft Actor-Critic Algorithms and Applications](https://arxiv.org/abs/1812.05905) by
Tuomas Haarnoja et al., which introduces an off-policy actor-critic DRL algorithm in the framework of entropy maximization. But I don't understand what is 'soft' about this algorithm. Is it because SAC is not maximization the true reward, but rather the reward and the entropy term?

Comment: "Soft" implies entropy regularisation. This type of regularisation is used in [soft Q-learning](https://arxiv.org/abs/1704.06440).